# BeautifulSoup: iteration over 24 char (from a to z) fails : reducing the complexity to get a first insight into the dataset:

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

i have a list of insurers in spain - it is collected in 24 rubriques - on a website: See the following

insurandes - espanol:
the full list: https://www.unespa.es/en/directory

it is divided into 24 pages:
https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#A
https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#Z

idea - what is aimed: i want to fetch the data from the pages- with  BS4 and request - and finally save it into a dataframe:
Well - the task of scraping the list  from the website using BeautifulSoup (BS4) and requests in Python seems to be apropiate; i think that we need to go the following steps:

**a.** firstly we need to import necessary libraries: BeautifulSoup, requests, and pandas.
**b.** then we need to use the requests library to get the HTML content of each of the pages that are interesting: i.e. A to Z-page.
**c.** then i  use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML content.
**d.** subsequently i think extracting the relevant information (insurers' names) from the parsed HTML is the next step
**e.** finally i want to store the extracted data in a pandas DataFrame.

but this does not work... - also not for the iteration from A to Z:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Function to scrape insurers from a given URL
def scrape_insurers(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        # Extracting insurer names
        insurers = [insurer.text.strip() for insurer in soup.find_all('h3')]
        return insurers
    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve data from", url)
        return []

# Define the base URL
base_url = "https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/"

# List to store all insurers
all_insurers = []

# Loop through each page (A to Z)
for char in range(65, 91):  # ASCII codes for A to Z
    page_url = f"{base_url}#{chr(char)}"
    insurers = scrape_insurers(page_url)
    all_insurers.extend(insurers)

# Convert the list of insurers to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Insurer': all_insurers})

# Display the DataFrame
print(df.head())

# Save DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('insurers_spain.csv', index=False)
```

....it fails with the following results:

```
Failed to retrieve data from https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#A
Failed to retrieve data from https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#B
Failed to retrieve data from https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#C
Failed to retrieve data from https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#D
Failed to retrieve data from https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#E
```

and so forth and so forth:

well i think it is quite easier to reduce the steps of complexity in the first place.

i think that its better to take one single URL i want to visit. It is just better to test what results we get back with our request. After this is finished, now i can evaluate the request; well i think i can use the beautiful soup lib to check for specific fields in common.
well i think that  i should avoid to do three things (which can obviously terrible wrong) in one step.

so i do it like so for the first character: for A:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to scrape insurers from a given URL
def scrape_insurers(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        # Extracting insurer names
        insurers = [insurer.text.strip() for insurer in soup.find_all('h3')]
        return insurers
    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve data from", url)
        return []

# Define the base URL
base_url = "https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#"

# Define the character we want to fetch data for
char = 'A'

# Construct the URL for the specified character
url = base_url + char

# Fetch and print data for the specified character
insurers_char = scrape_insurers(url)
print(f"Insurers for character '{char}':")
print(insurers_char)
```

but see the Output here:

```
Failed to retrieve data from https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/#A
Insurers for character 'A':
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.unespa.es/en/directory/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for c in soup.select(".contact-item"):
    for t in c.select("span, a"):
        t.unwrap()
    c.smooth()

    title, *other = c.get_text(separator="|||", strip=True).split("|||")
    data.append(
        {"Title": title, **{(s := d.split(":", maxsplit=1))[0]: s[1] for d in other}}
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                      Title                         Tfno.                           Fax                                                         Web                                                                                           Dirección                                          Email
0                               A.M.A., AGRUPACIÓN MUTUAL ASEGURADORA, MUTUA DE SEGUROS APF                  91 343 47 00                (91) 343 47 68                                   http://www.amaseguros.com                                                              VÍA DE LOS POBLADOS, 3 28033  (MADRID)                                            NaN
1                                                  ABANCA GENERALES DE SEGUROS Y REASEGUROS         881920742 / 881920744                           NaN                                                         NaN                                                  AV. LINARES RIVAS 30, 3º 15005 A CORUÑA (A CORUÑA)                                            NaN
2                                     ABANCA VIDA Y PENSIONES DE SEGUROS Y REASEGUROS, S.A.                   981 188 075                           NaN                                                         NaN                                         AVENIDA DE LA MARINA, 1-3ª PLANTA 15001 A CORUÑA (A CORUÑA)                                            NaN
3                                          ADMIRAL EUROPE COMPAÑIA DE SEGUROS S.A.U. (AECS)                           NaN                           NaN                              https://www.admiraleurope.com/                                               RODRÍGUEZ MARÍN, 61 - 1ª PLANTA 28016 MADRID (MADRID)                                            NaN
4                                    AEGON ESPAÑA, SOCIEDAD ANÓNIMA DE SEGUROS Y REASEGUROS                  91 563 62 22                           NaN                                         http://www.aegon.es                 VÍA DE LOS POBLADOS, 3 - EDIFICIO 4B - PARQUE EMPRESARIAL CRISTALIA 28033  (MADRID)                                            NaN
5                                          AGROPELAYO SOCIEDAD DE SEGUROS, SOCIEDAD ANÓNIMA                           NaN                           NaN                                                         NaN                                                             SANTA ENGRACIA, 67 - 69 28010  (MADRID)                                            NaN


...
```

Comment: dear Andrej - many thanks for the quick reply. Awesome. While trying this on Google-Colab i have to change the user-agent. ohterwise i get back ```empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```  - well this has to do with the user-agent. I will try out your approach tomorrow in the office -with pycharm on the linux notebook. Meanwhile many many thanks - and yes: i have to digg deeper into the user-agent-things - for the purpose of working with such scripts on google-colab. This approach takes some extra-steps to make scripts working well.  Besides this and above all: i am very glad to be here.